# Nil response when formatting date

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here's my server time:

2014-08-20 16:23:00.0

Now I would like to format the date my server gives me with the date only, and not the time. For example: Month/date/year Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Here's what I have tried:

```
 NSDate * date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"];

   NSString * dateForShow = //2014-08-20 16:23:00.0
    //Date returns nil
    date = [formatter dateFromString:dateForShow];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];


    NSString * result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Look at the actual date you have.  Look at the date format string.  How do they differ??  Then look at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.  How should the date format string be modified to look more like the actual date?

Comment: Better link to the ICU date formatting document: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your third line:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
```

Reference: [Link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Why didn't you reference the spec instead?

Comment: I still get a nil response.

Comment: wayon, please see my edited answer. We both had month and day mixed up. @HotLicks, what do you mean?

Comment: Rather than point at another SO issue, point at [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B), which every serious app programmer should have bookmarked (applies to Android as well).

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer. Funny thing is I had that page bookmarked but for some reason didn't think to reference it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you are trying to get me to realize that I can only date format string that is relative to what data comes into the string. Right?

Comment: @HotLicks did not see the update comment. Ok, so would I need to just parse the string to remove the time?

Comment: @wayon, your code is fine except for the initial date formatter. It must match the format in your string. See my updated answer.

Comment: @rebello95 you are the best, appreciate it!

Comment: See the date formatting document: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Use this format @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"